# Animate activity change as circular reveal

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I tried using android:windowEnterTransition and android:windowExitTransition but that seems to animate each view in the activity. How can I animate the whole activity with content on it? There are no shared elements between two activities.

Comment: Give more detail and/or show some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reveal animation does not work against windows. You can emulate it by targeting the contents of the window. I did this and it worked fine:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) (findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent());
    viewGroup.setTransitionGroup(true);
    RevealTransition transition = new RevealTransition();
    transition.addTarget(viewGroup);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(transition);
}
```

You have to start the activity with ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation.

One caveat -- I'm actually uncertain whether it is legal to use getParent() on android.R.id.content. I did that so that my action bar would be targeted as well. You should check that out yourself. I was only doing a quick test to see if reveal will work.

I know that this is a performance issue, but you will likely want to assign your window background to your content as well so that the circular reveal has a hard line. The window background color fades in. You can adjust the fade duration so that it doesn't fade in as fast as the reveal, but I didn't see a visual issue in my test -- maybe because of the colors I used.

Comment: Like Brian said, you can also manually reveal the Decor View if you don't have any shared elements.

Answer (score 0):

The circular reveal is a view animation. Skip the activity animation and then perform the view animation on your new activities root viewgroup.

Check out `InCallUi` source code in the Lollipop+ AOSP code for an example.

Comment: InCallUi uses a temporary blue fragment which circular reveals and then starts the target activity.